# Device option not visible in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Devices option in android studio toolbar is not visible due to which run option is not enabled I have cloned my project from my git repository.

[image: You can see device option is not visible]

-You can see the device option is not visible. 
-I have updated my android studio also dart and flutter plugin is updated to latest version.
-I have used all possible option like Invalidate cache/Restart, Update the studio

Also while running the command as `flutter doctor` device is available

Expected Result
[image]

Comment: Do you have usb debug mode enabled on device and authorized pc access?

Comment: yes USB debugging is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-I solved it by setting up the path of the dart from flutter SDK

go to  `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks` set path to `flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

Press the AVD Manager button and devices list will appear :

[image]

After selection and running a device it will appear as normal.

Comment: -On Pressing it shows an option to create a virtual device 
- My device is connected via USB which is still not appearing

Comment: create a virtual device and run it, and when the list appears choose your USB device. I've been into this strange behavior of `Android Studio 3` and this how I managed to solve it every time.

Comment: Still the device option is not visible